# Extra from one Matrix and add them to another?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

Have a matrix

$$
G =\left(\begin{array}{llll}2& 6& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
                  3& 9& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
                  0& 0& 1& 2& 0& 0\\
                  0& 0& 3& 4& 0& 0\\
                  1& 0& 0& 0& -5& 5\\
                  0& 1& 0& 0& 5& 3
\end{array}\right)
$$
I want to get the 4x4 of this matrix and add it to $H$ so

$$
H =\left(\begin{array}{llll}2& 6& 0& 0\\
                  3& 9& 0& 0\\
                  0& 0& 1& 2\\
                  0& 0& 3& 4\\                          
\end{array}\right)
$$

How would I do this with MatLab? I tried looking through there help but I couldn't seem to find it. Thanks in advance and sorry for the horrible formating.

Comment: The syntax is $G(1:4,1:4)$

Comment: Awesome thank! that worked great